# ckeditor not show in my admin panel this contains as a textarea

Tags: django, apache2

using the Django framework, add ck-editor in the admin panel, but show textarea I use python manage.py runserver and it works, but it doesn't work when deployed with Apache2.

[image]

Comment: You would have given wrong configuration in apache conf file for static path update code with configuration file.

Answer (score 0):

have you loaded ckeditor's static files on server?

run python manage.py collectstatic on server and restart application

Comment: I'm already try this method.

Comment: check you static paths in your settings first. go to ckeditor page on admin panel. right click -> inspect ->go to console reload the page and see if there are any errors while loading static files

Comment: show this error  in consol:-Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)   ckeditor-init.js:1 and ckeditor.js:1 and /favicon.ico:1

Comment: yessss that means your static paths are wrong brother.

Comment: please write the correct solutions........

Comment: can you share your static paths in your settings.py file? in server. and where is ckeditor's static files located?

Comment: settings.py code :- AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'services.User'
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
LOGIN_URL = '/login/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles')
STATICFILES_DIRS =(os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),)
DEFAULT_AUTO_FIELD='django.db.models.BigAutoField'

Comment: and your ckeditor static files are in static folder which is in base directory of your project right?

Comment: ckeditor directory store only staticfiles folder

Comment: if i'm run the python manage.py collectstatic commands                                                                         show the directoty    /home/ubuntu/Demo/website/staticfiles

Comment: please check in your staticfiles if there is folder 'ckeditor'?